# Java recursion - will this work?

Tags: java, recursion, methods

```
private void formatLines() {

    for (LineViewItem line:lineItems) {

        if (line.inLineItems.get(0).word.getText().equals(" ")) {

            line.inLineItems.remove(0); formatLines();

        }

        if (line.inLineItems.get(line.inLineItems.size()-1).word.getText().equals(" ")) {

            line.inLineItems.remove(line.inLineItems.size()-1); formatLines();

        }
    }
}
```

Above is a method I want to use in order to remove first or last object of each `line` in `lineItems` ArrayList if condition is `true`. When item is removed, then i want to repeat this process and check if there is another object at first and last position of each `line` in `lineItems` with `true` condition. That's why this method is called recursively. Does this work as it is supposed to work? I have a doubt if this works right.

Comment: `will this work?` Did you run this?

Comment: What does your unit test say?

Comment: yes, but im not sure if it works really as i think it works

Comment: incredible java recursion

Comment: Use linear structure rather than recursion for this. Something like `while (line.inLineItems.get(0).word.getText().equals(" ")) { line.inLineItems.remove(0); }`

Comment: That could work, but is somehting worng with my sloution?

Comment: @Antoniossss this is exactly why there should be far more resources on how to integrate JUnit into development and TDD, rather than just get crackin' with `public static void main(String[] args)`. Setting it up is a pain.

Comment: What do you think `line.inLineItems.remove(0); formatLines();` do?

Comment: @Zhuinden How come? I am using TestNG and it takes like 4 lines of dependencies in maven + test methods annotated with `@Test`. That is painfull?

Comment: @Antoniossss imagine being a total newbie and setting up a Maven project from scratch with only just having heard of "maven"

Comment: If not in maven than hey, lets include 1 jar (or 2) to the project....

Comment: Anyway it is not complicated, and I am surprised that you says otherwise

Comment: @Antoniossss it's just not really covered in any tutorial-level tutorial. Most things are not difficult once you figure out how to do them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will not work.

If a line has a lineItem with only one element, if you remove in the first if block, when you enter the 2nd if block you will reach

```
line.inLineItems.get(line.inLineItems.size()-1)
```

line.inLineItems.size() will be 0 and you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.